# Loss data when get many-to-many relationship web api 2 ef 6 code first

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

i have 2 classes that and have many-to-many relationship .

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerToken { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string  Agent { get; set; }
    public string  Phone { get; set; }
    public string  Email { get; set; }
    public string  Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpried { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Software> ListSoftwares { get; set; }
}

public class Software
{
    public Guid SoftwareID { get; set; }
    public int SoftwareCode { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRenewal { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateExpire { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> ListCustomers { get; set; }
}
```

I had 2 customers to test, and when I get all customer with their softwares, it just only get for one customer, missing data for another.

This my fuction to get all customers

```
 return db.Customers.Include((c) => c.ListSoftwares).ToList().OrderBy(cus => cus.CustomerToken);
```

In WebApiConfig, I also used:

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

I view on Chrome Dev Tools, run server to see result as json and i see Server return missing value, how can i fix it ?

Display a view using angularjs
[image: this image when i display in aview use angularjs]

Debug via Chrome Dev Tool
[image: this result when i debug]

Could someone help me please, thanks so much !

This's reponse data from server : 
[{"$id":"1","ListSoftwares":[{"$id":"2","ListCustomers":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$id":"3","ListSoftwares":[{"$ref":"2"},{"$id":"4","ListCustomers":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$ref":"3"}],"SoftwareID":"17aa20e4-5360-4513-8034-b2f4ce913637","SoftwareCode":2,"SoftwareName":"POS","LastRenewal":"2016-01-01T11:30:30.767","DateExpire":"2016-01-01T11:30:30.767"},{"$id":"5","ListCustomers":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$ref":"3"}],"SoftwareID":"ec57125b-3c30-413e-811e-b3c846994336","SoftwareCode":1,"SoftwareName":"BackOffice","LastRenewal":"2016-01-01T11:30:30.007","DateExpire":"2016-01-01T11:30:29.993"}],"CustomerID":"1fad71c0-8a9a-44aa-9adb-76a0a703c564","CustomerToken":"004","CustomerName":"Customer4","Agent":"Agent4","Phone":"","Email":"","Address":"","IsExpried":true}],"SoftwareID":"e4e687a9-b0c4-4b50-968a-6177582684e2","SoftwareCode":3,"SoftwareName":"GifCard","LastRenewal":"2016-01-01T11:30:31.783","DateExpire":"2016-01-01T11:30:31.783"},{"$ref":"4"},{"$ref":"5"}],"CustomerID":"15c2ea4c-d2f3-4f55-8720-6cea667f88dc","CustomerToken":"001","CustomerName":"Customer1","Agent":"Agent1","Phone":"","Email":"","Address":"","IsExpried":true},{"$id":"6","ListSoftwares":[],"CustomerID":"6671887d-456b-4db7-9a44-f2d6c36a7953","CustomerToken":"002","CustomerName":"Customer2","Agent":"Agent2","Phone":"","Email":"","Address":"","IsExpried":false},{"$id":"7","ListSoftwares":[],"CustomerID":"7b3bc240-d290-4277-ae8a-a0d1fdab935b","CustomerToken":"003","CustomerName":"Customer3","Agent":"Agent3","Phone":"","Email":"","Address":"","IsExpried":false},{"$ref":"3"}]

Comment: A general advice is to inspect what is returned from the server with for example Chrome DevTools. Can hopefully rule out either the server or the client.

Comment: thanks for respone, i cheked it via Chorm Dec Tools and run server to see json result and see the sever return missing values.

Comment: No problem :) If the server returns the correct data you should update your question by removing the server code and instead showing the relevant client code. Would also help if you include the JSON you saw in the Dev Tools.

Comment: but i can not find another way to get data with many-to-many relationship, i researched and find a way with use 'include'

Comment: Did you mean that the data that is returned from the server is missing data?

Comment: yes, i sure, i think reason is get data many-to-many relationship.but i don't know to fix or find solution. i just uploaded image when debug

Comment: Go to DevTools and the Network tab. Reload the page and find click the request that gets the data. Click the response tab. Can you show the response data?

Comment: I just post respone data. In database, customer1,and customer 4 have list softwares with 3 softwares. I see, when have only a customer1 contain softwarw, it return full data, but when i insert more softwares in another customer (customer4), it return loss data.

Comment: @tasseKATT : oh, i thinks my problem here is "Circular Reference". I and think i need diffirent way to get data. Thanks so much .